# Is it possible to find Smith Normal Form for a matrix of "variables"

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Is it possible to do Smith Normal form where the matrix has "variable" entries?

For instance consider the matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-b & 0 & 0 &-d\\
a & -c & 0 & 0\\
0 & b& -d & 0\\
0 & 0 & c &a
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are integers.

Is it possible to use the usual Smith Normal Algorithm to make the matrix into Smith Normal form, with explicit formulae in terms of $a,b,c,d$?

Looking at the algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form, it sure looks hard especially since in step II we need the Bezout property which is "existential" in the sense that there is no explicit formula to compute which linear combinations equal to the gcd.

This seems to be unlike Gaussian elimination where the algorithm works equally well for "variables".

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you may make use of the fact that, if the diagonal elements in the Smith normal form are $d_1,d_2,d_3,\ldots$, then $d_1d_2\cdots d_k$ is the $\gcd$ of all the determinants of the $k\times k$ submatrices of the original matrix. So $d_1=\gcd(a,b,c,d)$, $d_1d_2=\gcd(a^2, b^2, c^2, d^2, ab, ad, bc, cd)$ (if I am not mistaken), etc.

Comment: Since $a,b,c,d$ are "integers" but are really indeterminates, I think you're really working over the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[a,b,c,d]$.  Since this is not a PID, the Smith normal form is not guaranteed to exist over this ring.  I don't think you're going to get formulae any more explicit than in the comment above, since the value of the various $\gcd$s depends strongly on the value of $a,b,c,d$.